# asp classic: getting current path of a file located in a administrative folder

Tags: asp-classic

i have a file located at a folder whose full path is something like this:

> \mymachine\mydrive$\Inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder

is it possible through asp serverVariables to get the same value? i'm afraid of exposing the path above in my source code. thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in case anyone is wondering i found the solution. i used

```
Server.MapPath(".")
```

Comment: Thank you for actually returning with your own result. Quite rare to see.